Dynamically Change SQS Message Visibility Timeout in AWS Lambda
I have an AWS Lambda function triggered by an Amazon SQS queue. For certain messages, I need to delay processing for a specific time before handling them. However, I'm unsure how to achieve this within the Lambda execution context.
I don't have messages present in a batch.
When polling the queue from a Python script outside of Lambda, I can change the visibility timeout for a specific message using:
sqs.change_message_visibility(
   QueueUrl=queue_url,
   ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle,
   VisibilityTimeout=20
)


How can I implement a similar delay mechanism within a Lambda function triggered by SQS?
Is it advisable/can I use boto3 directly in the Lambda to change the visibility timeout of individual messages?
Should I instead set a global visibility timeout for all messages and throw an exception when I receive a message that cannot be processed immediately so that it can be retried by the lambda after the visibility timeout


Do you want to change the message visibility timeout of some messages in the queue, not all ? I presume you have the logic to flag the messages which you don't want to process immediately.

yes correct. If my message meets certain conditions, I want to delay the processing by some time and then retry it.

When sending a message to an Amazon SQS queue, you can specify DelaySeconds. I'm not 100% sure that will work with the SQS queue set as a trigger for the Lambda function, so give it a try and let us know what happens.
If your goal is to modify the timeout after a message has been sent, then this is not possible because you cannot selectively receive messages.
The preferred method would be to use a different SQS queue for messages that require different delays.
Note that the VisibilityTimeout is a mechanism for handling failure. It should not be used as a way to 'delay' the processing of messages.

Once the message is available in the queue, I check for certain conditions and if those are not met then I want to hold onto the message for sometime and then re-process it. What is the right way of doing it. The sender to the queue cannot check those conditions so I have to do it on the consumer side.

Queue-based architecture normally assumes that all messages are processed in the same way. The 'right way' would probably be to have Lambda notice that the message is an 'exception' and then on-send it to another queue for different processing. Or, I wonder if you can set a DelaySeconds as the default for ALL messages in the queue and that way you won't need to handle these particular messages in a different way?

Adding a delay for all the messages doesn't make sense for my use case as most messages are to be processed immediately except some messages that needs delayed processing. When I raise an 'exception' for a message my guess is that the message will again reappear in the queue after visibility timeout? If I send the message to another queue, is it a DLQ or a queue specifically designed to handle the delayed processing of the message. The processing logic for all the messages are same. It is just that some messages need delayed processing.

You are welcome to do as you wish. You asked for the 'right way of doing it', but generating an artificial exception and relying on the Invisibility Timeout is more of a 'cheat' than a 'right way'. But, your choice!

Was exploring different options. Thanks for all the help.
